# Windows Defender Blocking my dumb program

Tags: python

Hello I have no clue but windows defender is flagging my program but there is nothing in the code that should set it of. is there anyway to stop this? Could this be the turtle because it is making a screen? Or because of the random numbers?

```
import time
import random
import turtle

def click(x,y):
   player.penup()

    x = random.randint(-200, 200)

    y = random.randint(-250, 200)

    player.hideturtle()

    player.setpos(int(x), int(y))

    player.showturtle()

def stop():
   exit()


# The Screen
Screen = turtle.Screen()
Screen.bgcolor('black')
Screen.setup(900,900)
Screen.title('Triangle Game')


# Border Line
bl = turtle.Turtle()
bl.color('white')
bl.speed(9000)
bl.penup()
bl.setposition(-250, -250)
bl.pendown()
for i in range(4):
    bl.forward(500)
    bl.left(90)
    bl.hideturtle()

# Player Thing

player = turtle.Turtle()
player.shape('triangle')
player.color('white')


# click the player
player.onclick(click)


# Short Cut Keys
turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(stop, 'e')

 Screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this happen *before* the program even runs, if at all, or after is has started running?  Are you using something like Pyinstaller to make an *.exe file or are the other people running your code atop Python itself?

Comment: It does it when the program runs and I use auto py to exe when doing it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I faced similar issue and added below exception:

Go to Start > Settings > Update & Security > Windows Security > Virus & threat protection. Under Virus & threat protection settings, select Manage settings, and then under Exclusions, select Add or remove exclusions.

We can use virustotal website to analyse the possible cause.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but it's not for my PC its for other people who download it.

Comment: @JackLoza Then they can just do the following steps themselves. I've had my antivirus falsely flag many programs I have downloaded, and it was really easy to look up how to disable my antivirus in certain cases